# Unordered list (ul) with JSF and primefaces

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a list using basic HTML in my JSF 2.0 page, like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li><h:outputText value="Item1" /></li>
    <li><h:outputText value="Item2" /></li>
    <li><h:outputText value="Item3" /></li>
    <li><h:outputText value="Item4" /></li>
</ul>
```

But I don't want to show some items in some conditions, so I can use:

```
<ul>
    <li><h:outputText value="Item1" rendered="true"/></li>
    <li><h:outputText value="Item2" rendered="true"/></li>
    <li><h:outputText value="Item3" rendered="false"/></li>
    <li><h:outputText value="Item4" rendered="false"/></li>
</ul>
```

However, the list item is still being rendered and is breaking my page, so I was looking for something to replace the plain `<li>` item, so I can use the `rendered` option, or maybe some another idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to conditionally render the `<li>` as well. Wrap each of them in `<h:panelGroup>` or `<ui:fragment>`.

```html
<ul>
    <ui:fragment rendered="true"><li>Item1</li></ui:fragment>
    <ui:fragment rendered="true"><li>Item2</li></ui:fragment>
    <ui:fragment rendered="false"><li>Item3</li></ui:fragment>
    <ui:fragment rendered="false"><li>Item4</li></ui:fragment>
</ul>
```

Comment: This made it, but there isn't a `ui` and `li` alternative on JSF? :( oh, by the way, Thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome. No JSF doesn't have special components for that. That's also not necessary. Component libraries like PrimeFaces, RichFaces, Tomahawk, etc do however have a repeater component which renders `<ul><li>`, but it doesn't allow rendering the `<li>`s individually.